# What means the "-" in a &nbsp;-&nbsp; entity?

Tags: html

What means the `-` in a `-&nbsp;` entity?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special meaning for it, it is just a `dash` to be displayed prefixed and suffixed with spaces

Comment: The character “-” is hyphen (Unicode name: HYPHEN-MINUS), not dash.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing. It isn't part of the entity. It is just a hyphen that appears *before* the entity.

Comment: Indeed. But the construct as a whole does not make much sense. The hyphen (-) is probably meant to act as a dash (–). Moreover, contrary to specs, IE 9 and older do not honor the no-break space in this context but feels free to break the line after the hyphen (and put a leading space at the start of the next line). It is safer to use the `nobr` markup or the `white-space: nowrap` CSS setting for the piece of text that should be kept on one line.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't has any meaning, when you will run your code:

```
 &nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-&nbsp;
```

you will get output like

- - - - - - - - - - -

Answer (score 2):

Entities start with `&` and end with `;` everything outside is interpreted as is. so you have there only a dash followed by a non breaking space.